# Google's bill increase and DDoS-like attacks

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm assessing GCS as a CDN for assets used in handheld/desktop apps that I'd serve publicly. First question here, am I wrong using GCS as CDN ans should look elsewhere?

Now my main question. A malicious user creates a program and performs zillions of "Class B operations" against my resources, say 100x the normal rate from legitimate users, my bill for "Class B operations" will increase accordingly. Does google do anything to prevent this kind of issues? Is there anything I can do to protect against it?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

For your first question it really depends on your need, we are using CloudFlare instead of Google Cloud but our all infrastructure is on Google cloud. I read details about Gcloud CDN here https://cloud.google.com/solutions/cdn-fastly
Also you can read a comparison here http://www.baldnerd.com/make-your-site-faster-cloudflares-cdnjs-vs-google-hosted-libraries-shocking-results/

For your second question have a look at [How Google Load Balancer handles DDoS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824149/how-google-load-balancer-handles-ddos) this explains it to some extent.